# How can I add different images to a post for different category view in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have three categories like cat1, cat2, cat3. Also, I have a post with featured image. My problem is I need to show this post under the each categories with different image.

Comment: Are you trying to have unique category images regardless of what post is showing? If no then you need to create a custom field to achieve what you need.

Comment: your question isn't clear at all. What image do you want to show? The featured image for the post? An image for the category? Both?

Comment: I need to add multiple featured image to a post and the same post should show under all categories with different images. I need two images. One which can be uploaded for the features header, as well as the post header. Additionally, I need an image that can be shown in the 'spotlight' category, the 'article category' as well as the latest white papers list.

Comment: @AnuRaj Think about advance custom field plug-in that solve you problem. You can assign different image upload option depends on your category in this. I hope this is better than multiple featured image concept.